# Facebook app domain not recognized

Tags: facebook, dns

I registered a new facebook app "myapp" and added a website to it with url "myapp.com". In dashboard->settings->basic I set App Domains to "myapp.com" and "myapp.dev". The myapp.dev (mapped on my machine) works fine. But the ".com" gives:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

But it's right there in the settings when I check! 
I used to have another facebook app running on the server but from a different domain, then working just fine. Could there be some kind of conflict on that IP? Do I need to set some special DNS? I'm out of ideas would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubled checked the DNS again and only found a record for myapp.com, www.myapp.com was missing which was the one facebook tried to use.

Might also be I needed to add both www.myapp.com and myapp.com in the App Domains.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a new platform first.
in this setting page, at the bottom, there is a button "add new platform" click it and choose website and then you will be asked for the app domain.